# Activation error when using Prism and Unity container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, prism

I have the following console program in which I attempt to apply the SOLID principles, dependency injection with Unity and Prism 6 modularity:

Main program:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterInstance<IServiceLocator>(new UnityServiceLocator(container));

            container.RegisterType<IModuleInitializer, ModuleInitializer>();

            TextLogger logger = new TextLogger();
            container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerFacade>(logger);

            ConfigurationModuleCatalog catalog = new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
            container.RegisterInstance<IModuleCatalog>(catalog);

            container.RegisterType<IModuleManager, ModuleManager>();

            IModuleManager manager = container.Resolve<IModuleManager>();
            manager.Run();
```

App config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf" />
  </configSections>

  <modules>

    <module assemblyFile="CalcCommandParsingLib.dll" moduleType="CalcCommandParsingLib.CalculatorCommandParsingModule, CalcCommandParsingLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="Parsing" />

    <module assemblyFile="CalculatorLibrary.dll" moduleType="CalculatorLibrary.CalculatorModule, CalculatorLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="Calculator" />

    <module assemblyFile="InputOutputLibrary.dll" moduleType="InputOutputLibrary.InputOutputModule, InputOutputLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="InputOutput" />

    <module assemblyFile="MainModuleLibrary.dll" moduleType="MainModuleLibrary.MainModule, MainModuleLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="Main" >
      <dependencies>
        <dependency moduleName="Calculator" />
        <dependency moduleName="Parsing" />
        <dependency moduleName="InputOutput" />
      </dependencies>
    </module>

  </modules>

</configuration>
```

And one of the four modules which causes the error:

```
public class MainModule : IModule
    {
        IServiceLocator serviceLocator;

        public MainModule(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
        {
            this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            ICalculatorReplLoop loop = serviceLocator.GetInstance<ICalculatorReplLoop>();
            loop.Run();
        }
    }
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
ICalculatorReplLoop loop = serviceLocator.GetInstance<ICalculatorReplLoop>();
```

and it is:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: Activation error occurred while trying to get
>   instance of type ICalculatorReplLoop, key ""

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are at least 2 things to change:

1. You should also register ICalculatorReplLoop

   `container.RegisterType<ICalculatorReplLoop, CalculatorReplLoop>();`
2. It would make more sense for me to inject directly the needed interface, then to resolve it via serviceLocator so:

   `public MainModule(ICalculatorReplLoop calc)
     {
          this.calc= calc;
     }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the service locator was used intentionally in order to reduce some coupling. The example I have is actually from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNVF8k_II9Y except that I use Prism 6

Comment: Well, second point wasn't really resolving the issue you had, and you are probably right, it makes code a bit less coupled. The issue you are having is related to the first point: unity cannot find a registration the interface you are trying to resolve. It MUST be registered before you are resolving it.

Comment: I don't think coupling is reduced this way, it is hidden in the implementation. Directly injecting the `ICalculatorReplLoop` says "hey, I depend on a `ICalculatorReplLoop` implementation!", while injecting the service locator just says "I depend on stuff, but you have to guess what exactly, good luck with that..."

Comment: Don't inject the ServiceLocator.  Inject the class dependency directly. If your class requires the ICalculatorRepolLoop to function, then you have already created a coupling with that class, and now all you are doing is hiding that requirement.  Plus, you're making your testing much harder than it has to be. ServiceLocator is an anti-pattern and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Also, you should be able to use the UnityBootstapper in the Console app directly, so you don't have to copy/paste all it's functionality into your console app. Just don't override the CreatShell or InitializeShell methods.